# can i deploy a django web app on a web server i can't configure?

Tags: django, webserver, backend, web-development-server, embeddedwebserver

So we got a project at uni to create a website. We have not received any specific on what technologies to use, we were only given a theme. These projects will end up hosted on the uni website. The host for the website is:

```
http://uni.co.uk
```

The projects will end up at the url:

```
http://uni.co.uk/module_code/projects/
```

Normally, the tutor expects just a front-end solution with a bundle of html, css and javascript files. I would like to add some back-end to make the website dynamic.

I have played around with Django and node.js and I quite fancy Django and want to give it a try for this project. My only issue is that the web server my project will end up on is not accessible to me and I can't configure it. Is there any way I can still use some back-end in my project if I cannot access the main host web server configuration ? Any way I can create my own tiny web server at that url where my project ends up ?

Not expecting any code solutions, if someone could just tell me if this is possible and point me to the right resource for information.

I do apologize if the question is ambiguous, but I am new to web development and not sure how to make the question more technical.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will it be better to contact website administrator and ask him if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is call a backend that you've developed and deployed somewhere else with javascript. So essentially you'd end up with a solution where you have html and javascript hosted at the uni website and then the backend hosted somewhere else. So the backend would work as your api.

I would suggest deploying on heroku, because it's relatively easy to deploy there.

One issue that might crop up is [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) since you'll have the backend on one domain and javascript on another.

Take a look at some resources for how to build a single page app. Most of them will mention resources on how to handle api requests because they'll rely on those.